# Latest two datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have following table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[events]
(
    [event_id] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [event_timestamp] [datetime] NULL,
    [reading] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

with the following data and resutls

Table: `events`

```
event_id  event_timestamp    Reading
---------------------------------
1200      14-Jun-15          1500
1200      13-Jun-15          1430.7
1200      12-Jun-15          1400.9
1200      11-Jun-15          1333.2
1200      10-Jun-15          1233.7
1330      14-Jun-15          1490
1330      13-Jun-15          1300
1330      12-Jun-15          1200
1330      11-Jun-15          1150
1330      10-Jun-15          1000
1347      14-Jun-15          2700
1347      13-Jun-15          2400
1347      12-Jun-15          2350
1347      11-Jun-15          2300
1347      10-Jun-15          2100
```

The result should be

Required result:

```
event_id    event_timestamp    Reading
--------------------------------------
1200        14-Jun-15          1500
1200        13-Jun-15          1430.7
1330        14-Jun-15          1490
1330        13-Jun-15          1300
1347        14-Jun-15          2700
1347        13-Jun-15          2400
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `row_number` function:

```
with cte as(select *, row_number() over(partition by event_id 
                         order by event_timestamp desc) rn from events)
select * from cte where rn <= 2
```

Comment: with cte as(select itemid, dt, info, row_number() over(partition by itemid order by dt desc) rn 
from (SELECT itemid, dt, MAX(info) info from(
SELECT event_item_id itemid,CONVERT(VARCHAR, event_timestamp, 111) dt, event_additional_info info
FROM dbo.events WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, event_timestamp, 111) IN (  
SELECT Distinct(CONVERT(VARCHAR, event_timestamp, 111))FROM dbo.events 
WHERE event_additional_info!='0.000000')
) tbl1 GROUP BY itemid, dt
) tbl)
select * from cte where rn <= 2 ORDER BY itemid DESC, dt DESC

Answer (score 0):

@Giorgi Nakeuri, Thanks a lot for your help, I got it.

```
with cte as(select itemid, dt, info, row_number() over(partition by itemid order by dt desc) rn 
from (SELECT itemid, dt, MAX(info) info from(
SELECT event_item_id itemid,CONVERT(VARCHAR, event_timestamp, 111) dt, Reading info
FROM dbo.events WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, event_timestamp, 111) IN (  
SELECT Distinct(CONVERT(VARCHAR, event_timestamp, 111))FROM dbo.events 
WHERE Reading !='0.000000')
) tbl1 GROUP BY itemid, dt
) tbl)
select * from cte where rn <= 2 ORDER BY itemid DESC, dt DESC
```